# How can you test if a variable is of type of a type alias?

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a type alias:

```
AnyPath = Type[int] | Type[str] | Type[bytes] | Type[os.PathLike[str]] | Type[os.PathLike[bytes]]
```

This is the same type alias used by the `os.chdir` function for example.

```py
def is_path(path)->bool:
    if type(path) is AnyPath:
        return True # never yields true
    elif isinstance(path, AnyPath): 
        # raises TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks 
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Related: [Python 3: TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70825351/python-3-typeerror-subscripted-generics-cannot-be-used-with-class-and-instance)

Comment: It is very important to understand, `Type[int] | Type[str] | Type[bytes] | Type[os.PathLike[str]] | Type[os.PathLike[bytes]]` **is not a type**. it is a *type annotation*. You probably just shouldn't try to use it like a type.

Comment: I called it type alias in this question. A type annotation is `my_int:int=4`

Answer (score 0):

Several things need to be understood to solve this problem:

1. If AnyPath were defined like this `int | str | bytes` it would work fine.
2. However, if `AnyPath` contains `os.PathLike[str]`, it doesn't work again. `type(os.PathLike[str]) is GenericAlias`
3. If `AnyPath` contains `os.PathLike` instead, it works again. `type(os.PathLike) is abc.ABCMeta`
4. `os.PathLike.__subclasshook__.__self__ = os.PathLike[str].__subclasshook__.__self__ = os.PathLike`
5. The `__args__` attribute of a `Union` or `Type` is a `tuple` containing all the subtypes. Example: `Type[int].__args__[0] is int`

So I tried this solution. Just copy and try it out. I would love some comments on improving the answer:

```py
from types import GenericAlias
from typing import Type,_UnionGenericAlias,_GenericAlias
import os

def get_types_from_typing(t):
    result = []
    def recursive(t):
        if type(t) in (_UnionGenericAlias,_GenericAlias):
            for arg in t.__args__:
                recursive(arg)
        elif type(t) is GenericAlias:
            result.append(t.__subclasshook__.__self__)
        else:
            result.append(t)
    recursive(t)
    return result

AnyPath = int | str | bytes | os.PathLike 
print(get_types_from_typing(AnyPath)) #-> (<class 'os.PathLike'>, <class 'bytes'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)

AnyPath = Type[int] | Type[str] | Type[bytes] | Type[os.PathLike[str]] | Type[os.PathLike[bytes]]
print(get_types_from_typing(AnyPath)) #-> (<class 'os.PathLike'>, <class 'bytes'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'int'>)
   
# Test1
def is_path(path: "AnyPath"):
    if type(path) is AnyPath:
        return True
    elif isinstance(path,AnyPath):
        return True
    else:
        return False

try:
    print(is_path("4"))
    print(is_path(4))
    print(is_path(["4","5"]))
except TypeError as e:
    print("is_path failed:", e.args[0])

#Test2
def is_path(path: "AnyPath"):
    safe_AnyPath = get_types_from_typing(AnyPath)
    return isinstance(path,safe_AnyPath)

try:
    class Example: pass
    example = Example()
    print(is_path("4"))
    print(is_path(4))
    print(is_path(["4","5"]))
    print(is_path(example))
except TypeError:
    print("is_path failed")
```

Comment: "If AnyPath were defined like this int | str | bytes it would work fine." no, no it wouldn't.

Comment: `isinstance(4,int | str | bytes)` returns True and `isinstance(4,int | str | bytes)` returns True too

Comment: I meant `isinstance("4",int | str | bytes)` returns True